# How to remove style properties in TestCafe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

How can I remove CSS properties on client side using [TestCafe](https://testcafe.devexpress.com/) on a [React](https://reactjs.org/) build?

Currently I'm working for a client where [polylines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polyline) are drawn, but I am not able to compare DOM results to the original because of the following style attribute `transform: matrix(1.4043, 0, 0, 1.4043, 40.5, 0);`, which scales the DOM elements.

I'm not able to find any solution so my question is: how can I remove this style attribute?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to use the [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/):

```
const getStyleAttribute = ClientFunction((selector) => {
    const element = selector();
    return element.getAttribute('style');
});

const setStyleAttribute = ClientFunction((selector, styleValue) => {
    const element = selector();
    element.setAttribute('style', styleValue);
});

const field = Selector('your selector');
const styles = await getStyleAttribute(field) || '';
const updatedStyles = 
`${styles} background-color: red; transform: matrix(1.4043, 0, 0, 1.4043, 40.5, 0);`;

await setStyleAttribute(field, updatedStyles);
```

The above exemple is adding a transform and a background color. You may adapt this code to remove styles instead.

Do not forget to import `ClientFunction` in the test file.